# Making div show outside Angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/EtBZSbpwxPnsk8GmSf2M?p=preview)  I have an Angular UI modal with a div that's inside the modal, but since it has `position:fixed` I'm expecting the div to be outside and cover the entire screen. Why is it inside the modal and how to make this work? Note that the div has to be inside the modal.

HTML

```
<style>
  .app-modal .modal-dialog {
      width: 260px;
      height:100px;
    }
  div#background {
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      background-color:orange;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div id="background"></div>
     Some text in the div
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, your height says 1oo instead of 100. Also, the text of the div is outside the div tag. Moreover, the width and height of .modal-dialog restrict the width and height of the div, as that is the container. If you set those to 100% each also, you will see it does expand all the way

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the 100, and still have the same problem. The text of the div is outside the tag because it belongs to the modal itself, not to the background. Question is: if position is fixed and top/left are zero, why isn't the background positioned in the top/left of the screen instead of the modal? The background div should be independent as its position is `fixed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comment discussion, I'm following up with an answer.

As mentioned in the above comment, fixing the height and width of your initial container element, expands the div to the whole screen.

The remaining problem of a 'border' around the div is because of a border set by the framework on the modal. You can go around that by setting

```
margin: 0;
```

on the modal-dialog class.

Here's an updated plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ycuD0OU8PRj5j4qiZnDw?p=preview

Comment: I cannot expand the container, I need it to remain as is. The background color has to cover the screen behind the container.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand what you're trying to do now. I thought you wanted the orange box to take the size of the whole screen. If you're just trying to change the modal's backdrop colour, you should probably do that with just CSS. Maybe try making a picture mockup of what you're trying to do.